# Function for bayesian information criterion (BIC)

Tags: bayesian, mathematical-statistics, python, bic

I am writing my own python function for the bayesian information criterion (BIC) calculation. What I want to do is to choose between two models that I fitted with a set of discrete xy data points.

I followed the theory [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_information_criterion) and I wrote the solution for the Gaussian special case (`BIC = n*log(residual sum of squares/n) + k*log(n)`).

The code is the following:

```
n = len(y_data_tot) # number of data points
k = 6 # model free parameters
summ = 0 # summatory of (data - model)**2
for i in range(n):
    diffsqrt = (y_data_tot[i] - y_model_tot[i])**2
    summ = summ + diffsqrt

rsos = (1/n)*summ

BIC = n*np.log(rsos/n) + k*np.log(n)
```

Now, I have the following questions:

- is the Gaussian case a reasonable approximation?
- is `k` the number of free parameters or the total number of parameters (I have models with frozen/static parameters)?

Answer (score 1):

- I think the Gaussian approximation problem is rather a question for the model you choose to fit. If you are doing a linear regression using least square, this corresponds to fitting a Gaussian model by maximum likelihood and you must use the BIC for the Gaussian special case. If you use another model, you should compute the corresponding BIC. You can check if a Gaussian model is reasonable or not by a quantile plot of the residuals for example.

  - The number of parameters $k$ to use in your BIC is the number of parameter you fit in your model. So this the number of free parameters.

Hope it helped